# How can I remove/unimport symbols from __future__ after importing them?

Tags: python

In python 2.x, dividing two integers returns an integer. However, if you use

```
from ___future___ import division
```

you can get a float value:

```
>>> 3/2
1
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 3/2
1.5
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 3//2
1
>>> 4/3
1.3333333333333333
>>>
```

After the `import`, you have to use `//` instead of `/` to do integer division. How can I revert the `import` so that `/` does integer division again?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`__future__` imports are special, and cannot be undone.  You can read up on their behavior [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#future-statements).

Here are a few relevant portions:

> A future statement is recognized and treated specially at compile time: Changes to the semantics of core constructs are often implemented by generating different code. It may even be the case that a new feature introduces new incompatible syntax (such as a new reserved word), in which case the compiler may need to parse the module differently. Such decisions cannot be pushed off until runtime.
>   ...
>   A future statement typed at an interactive interpreter prompt will take effect for the rest of the interpreter session.

Since `__future__` statements are handled at compile time as opposed to runtime, there is no runtime method for reverting the changed behavior.

With normal modules you can remove or unimport the module by deleting whatever you imported from the namespace, and deleting the entry for that import in [`sys.modules`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.modules) (this second part may not be necessary depending on the use case, all it does is force the reloading of the module if it is imported again).

Comment: +1 to both this answer (which explains the problem) and Brendan Long's (which explains how the OP can actually do what he wants to do).

Comment: Note also that extension modules (_i.e._ those written in compiled languages like C) can't be unloaded, because they are integrated into the interpreter's address space on import.

Answer (score 5):

`import` statements are local to the file you import in, so for example, if you have this file as `example.py`:

```
from __future__ import division
print(1/2)
```

Then you load it in another file:

```
import example # prints 0.5 because `division` is imported in example.py
print(1/2) # prints 0 because `division` is not imported in this file
```

So if you want an import that's only used in some of your code, put that code in a separate file.

In the case you gave, I'm not sure it's helpful though. Why not just use `//` when you need integer division?

Comment: One answer why someone would want to "unimport" future-division is unit tests. I'm overloading the division operators and want to verify single-slash behavior in Python 2. I could call `__div__()` directly. Your answer may be a better solution: tests with single-slash in a different source file.